# PHP - cakephp version issue

Tags: php, cakephp-3.0

I am using cakephp version 3.3.16

I got the following errors after upgrading php version to 7.4.

> Warning (2): count() [function.count]: Parameter
> must be an array or an object that implements Countable
> [CORE/src/Database/QueryCompiler.php, line 128]

Anybody please help me to solve this issue

Thanks in advance!

Comment: it sounds the _sqlCompiler function is using the count function without a countable validation.

its possible you need to run the `composer install` again and see if that fixs these kind of issues. Cakephp 3.3.16 doesnt have the validation you could see [here](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/3.x/src/Database/QueryCompiler.php) in line 129.

if you check vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Database/QueryCompiler.php in your repo, you probably will see `if (!count($parts)) { return; }` and it should have something like `((is_array($parts) || $parts instanceof \Countable) && !count($parts))`

Comment: if (
                !isset($parts) ||
                ((is_array($parts) || $parts instanceof \Countable) && !count($parts))
            ) {
                return;
            }

Comment: You're not supposed to edit vendor code! Update your CakePHP dependency instead, this bug has been fixed something like 5 years ago in version 3.4.10: **https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/pull/10864**

Comment: Exactly, as @ndm mentioned, you shouldnt edit vendor code. I tried to explain you that you need to update your vendor code with a cakephp version greater than you have currently.